# python: import problems with directory structure that keeps scripts and modules separate

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have the following directory structure:

```
app/
  bin/
    script1.py
    script2.py
  lib/
    module1/
      __init__.py
      module1a.py
      module1b.py
    __init__.py
    module2.py
  Dockerfile
```

My problem is that I want to *execute* `script1.py` and `script2.py`, but inside those scripts, I want to import the modules in `lib/`.

I run my scripts from the root `app/` directory (i.e. adjacent to `Dockerfile`) by simply executing `python bin/script1.py`.  When I import modules into my scripts using `from lib.module1 import module1a`, I get `ImportError: No module named lib.module1`.  When I try to import using relative imports, such as `from ..lib.module1 import module1a`, I get `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

When I simply fire up the interpreter and run `import lib.module1` or something, I have no issues.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Without adding `/path/to/app` to `PYTHONPATH`, you cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need `__init__.py` under `app` and `bin`, then you can do a relative import, but that expects a package

If you would structure your python code as python package (egg/wheel) then you could also define an entry point, that would become your `/bin/` file post install.

here is an example of a package - https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html

and this blog explains entry points quite well - https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/

if so, that way you could just do `python setup.py install` on your package and then have those entry points available within your `PATH`, as part of that you would start to structure your code in a way that would not create import issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the Python path at runtime in script1.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/your/app/')
import lib.module1.module1a
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to add current dir to python path.

use export in terminal 
or sys.path.insert in your python script both are ok